# How to change https://<your-url>/swagger to custom in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, swagger-editor

I was tasked to install Swagger into Web API project.

Installed: most recent version of Swashbuckle from nuget. (Swashbuckle.Core.Net45 and Swashbuckle.Net45)

Customized: App_Start\SwaggerConfig.cs. I was able to customize (change styles, added logo, modified descriptions)..

Now we need to change from https://[your-url]/swagger to https://[your-url]/help

Please advise

Answer (score 4):

Change `routePrefix` of `SwaggerUIOptions` parameter, default is "swagger"

Answer (score 3):

How about following the [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#custom-routes)? In your case you could change the `SwaggerConfig` to

```
httpConfiguration
    .EnableSwaggerUi("help/{*assetPath}");
```

The documentation can then be found at https://[your-url]/help/index

Comment: How to change the documentation path from https://[your-url]/help/index to https://[your-url]/help and additionally - to make it work for https://[your-url]/help and https://[your-url]/help/