# Springfox - change path of swagger-ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

now swagger is served from  http://localhost:8080/myContextRoot/swagger-ui.html

Can I configure swagger and its resources to be served under http://localhost:8080/myContextRoot/swagger/swagger-ui.html

thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change https://<your-url>/swagger to custom in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944432/how-to-change-https-your-url-swagger-to-custom-in-swagger)

Comment: No, but thank you for your answer. This discussion  helped me a lot.
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed this approach:

Dependency:

```
implementation 'org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:4.0.4'
```

UrlRewrite Class:

```
@Component
public class SwaggerUrlRewriteFilter extends UrlRewriteFilter {
  private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "/urlrewrite.xml";

  @Value("classpath:/urlrewrite.xml")
  private Resource resource;

  @Override
  protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
      //Create a UrlRewrite Conf object with the injected resource
      Conf conf = new Conf(filterConfig.getServletContext(), resource.getInputStream(), resource.getFilename(), "@@yourOwnSystemId@@");
      checkConf(conf);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new ServletException("Unable to load URL rewrite configuration file from " + CONFIG_LOCATION, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

and in the resource folder urlrewrite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>/swagger/swagger-ui.html</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/swagger-ui.html</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/swagger/webjars/(.*)</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/webjars/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/swagger/v2/api-docs</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/v2/api-docs</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/swagger/configuration/(.*)</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/configuration/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <from>/swagger/swagger-resources</from>
        <to type="passthrough">/swagger-resources</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

after that the path to swagger is:

http://localhost:8080/myContextRoot/swagger/swagger-ui.html